# Laravel Cashier - Multiple subscriptions for a single user

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, stripe-payments

I would like to allow each user the ability to subscribe to multiple services. I know that Stripe has this ability but it seems to be a 1:1 within laravel cashier. Has anyone had success extending cashier to allow for this?

Comment: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/billing

Answer (score 2):

I just asked the same question to TaylorOtwell himself in [Laravel.io](http://laravel.io), and the answer is no. It doesn't support multiple subscription for a single user for now.
There is a solution suggested [here](https://laracasts.com/forum/?p=1542-laravel-cashier/0), but there are no clear guides are any result reports so far.

Clearly the way to go is to bypass the cashier for that matter.